# what is target id in this code

Tags: iphone, facebook

what is target id is it application id or what. what should be its data type.

```
NSString *message = @"test message here";
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[params setObject:message forKey:@"message"];
[params setObject:toID forKey:@"target_id"];
[[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"facebook.Stream.publish" params:params];
```

please answer soon....

Answer (score 1):

Read the beginning of [this post](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish).

Answer (score 0):

Its a key in `params`. from the looks of things (not for sure, since you provide basically no code or context of the code) it is a string that contains the ID to which you are sending your facebook request. Try looking in the API for the Library you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Documented here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish

> The ID of the user, Page, group, or
>   event where you are publishing the
>   content. If you specify a target_id,
>   the post appears on the Wall of the
>   target profile, Page, group, or event,
>   not on the Wall of the user who
>   published the post. This mimics the
>   action of posting on a friend's Wall
>   on Facebook itself.